# xslt sort based on mutually exclusive element

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an xml data where there are 2 date elements `<STRT_DT>` and `<STRT_BY_DT>`. These 2 elements are mutually exclusive. I need to sort the XML aggregate with these dates in ascending order by date. Sample Instance:

`<EVNT>`
 `<LGL_EVNT>`
 `<STRT_DT>2017-11-01</STRT_DT>`
 `<EVNT_TYP_CD>10</EVNT_TYP_CD>`
`</LGL_EVNT>`
`<LGL_EVNT>`
 `<STRT_BY_DT>2017-11-02</STRT_BY_DT>`
 `<EVNT_TYP_CD>10</EVNT_TYP_CD>`
`</LGL_EVNT>`
`<LGL_EVNT>`
 `<STRT_DT>2017-10-02</STRT_DT>`
 `<EVNT_TYP_CD>10</EVNT_TYP_CD>`
`</LGL_EVNT>`
`<LGL_EVNT>`
 `<STRT_BY_DT>2017-10-03</STRT_BY_DT>`
 `<EVNT_TYP_CD>10</EVNT_TYP_CD>`
`</LGL_EVNT>`
`</EVNT>`

Expected Output is to get the Legal Event aggregate in ascending order:

`<EVNT>`
`<LGL_EVNT>`
 `<STRT_DT>2017-10-02</STRT_DT>`
 `<EVNT_TYP_CD>10</EVNT_TYP_CD>`
`</LGL_EVNT>`
`<LGL_EVNT>`
 `<STRT_BY_DT>2017-10-03</STRT_BY_DT>`
 `<EVNT_TYP_CD>10</EVNT_TYP_CD>`
`</LGL_EVNT>`
`<LGL_EVNT>`
 `<STRT_DT>2017-11-01</STRT_DT>`
 `<EVNT_TYP_CD>10</EVNT_TYP_CD>`
`</LGL_EVNT>`
`<LGL_EVNT>`
 `<STRT_BY_DT>2017-11-02</STRT_BY_DT>`
 `<EVNT_TYP_CD>10</EVNT_TYP_CD>`
`</LGL_EVNT>`
`</EVNT>`

I am not able to sort based on these 2 mutually exclusive elements using xslt 2.0. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an `xsl:sort` with a sequence of two dates constructed from the two elements, as they are mutually exclusive there will only one sort key for each element:

```
<xsl:template match="EVNT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LGL_EVNT">
            <xsl:sort select="xs:date(STRT_DT) , xs:date(STRT_BY_DT)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Add the identity transformation template to that (or use XSLT 3 and `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tried this but I am getting an error "Too many items, expected '1', '2' was supplied

Comment: Are there elements `LGL_EVNT`  that have both a `STRT_DT` and a `STRT_BY_DT` child? If they are mutually exclusive I don't see where you would get that error and I run the code with Saxon 9.7 and 9.8 HE against your input without problems.

Comment: If you've copied MH's code correctly and are getting the error you report, then it would appear that your description of your input is incorrect and that STRT_DT and STRT_BY_DT are not mutually exclusive after all.  Figure out which takes priority in that case and adjust the select expression to return only one value:  `(xs:date(STRT_DT) , xs:date(STRT_BY_DT))[1]` should work.

Comment: Thanks very much Martin, there were some EVNT which were having both dates erroneously. I am getting the correct results now.

Comment: Many Thanks for your feedback McQueen, will look into this.

Comment: @Siddharth - if your question has been answered, you should 'accept' the answer by clicking on the 'Accept' button you will see next to the answer.  Otherwise, the Stack Overflow software treats your question as one that still lacks a satisfactory answer.